# IOS : Rough behaviour at the boundaries of google maps

Tags: ios, google-maps, google-maps-sdk-ios

I am using google maps sdk for IOS. I have set the boundaries for the map using GMSCoordinateBounds() method.

I am experiencing some issues while scrolling at the boundaries of the map. 
Not sure, if this is the IOS native behaviour or something related to code.

Actual behaviour :
Experiencing rough behaviour at the boundaries.
Working fine inside the bounds.

Expected behaviour :
It should stop scroll or zoom in effect at the boundaries, to avoid rough behaviour.

Here is my code

```
var mapView = GMSMapView()
var defaultCamera = GMSCameraPosition()
defaultCamera = GMSCameraPosition(target: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 12.3019, longitude: 104.0923),
                                      zoom: zoomLevels[0],
                                      bearing: defaultCamera.bearing,
                                      viewingAngle: defaultCamera.viewingAngle)
mapView.delegate = self
mapView.mapStyle = MapUtils().style
mapView.camera = defaultCamera
mapView.setMinZoom(10, maxZoom: 21)
// enable google map view handle other gesture
mapView.settings.consumesGesturesInView = false
mapView.settings.rotateGestures = false
mapView.settings.tiltGestures = false
mapView.settings.allowScrollGesturesDuringRotateOrZoom = false
// override double tap to zoom in
let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(googleMapDoubleTap))
tapGesture.numberOfTapsRequired = 2
mapView.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)

self.myLocationMarker.map = self.mapView
```

Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to simply add this line when configuring `GMSMapview`:

```
_mapView.settings.allowScrollGesturesDuringRotateOrZoom = NO;
```

or

You can use this line [allowScrollGesturesDuringRotateOrZoom](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/reference/interface_g_m_s_u_i_settings#overview) to your `GMSMapview`. It controls whether rotate and zoom gestures can be performed off-center and scrolled around. The default value of this is YES.

```
mapView.settings.allowScrollGesturesDuringRotateOrZoom = false // NO for obj-c and false for swift
```

So by setting it by NO/false, you can now perform zooming while the marker location is not moving.

Comment: Ok! Thanks a lot @MdRashedPervez.
Will see if it works and let you know

Comment: Hi @MdRashedPervez. Sorry to say,, but it is not working

Comment: same error shows? did you set the _mapView.settings.allowScrollGesturesDuringRotateOrZoom = NO; in your GMSMapview ?

Comment: I did set it to false

Comment: if you share your code here it will be lot more easier to understand. Did you set your constrains to 0 when adding the mapkitView ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166219/discussion-between-md-rashed-pervez-and-deepak-terse).